# $f(z)=f(iz)\forall z$, my question is : is there such $f$ exists?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\le c|z|^3\forall |z|\ge 3,f(z)=f(iz)\forall z$, my question is : is there such $f$ exists?

$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+a_4z^4+a_5z^5+\dots=a_0+a_1iz-a_2z^2-ia_3z^3+a_4z^4+ia_5z^5\dots$

$|g(z)|=|{f(z)\over z^3}|\le c\forall |z|\ge 3$ so by Liuvilles $f(z)=kz^3\forall |z|\ge 3$ also $kz^3=-ki z^3$ so $k=0$, so $f(z)=0\forall |z|\ge 3$? so $f\equiv 0$? am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: This is hard to read. Could you put some more efforts in formatting the question please? :-)

Comment: What does $f(z)\le cz^3$ mean? Unless we know that $f(z)$ and $cz^3$ are both real, there's no natural way to talk about them being ordered. Should it perhaps read $|f(z)|\le c|z|^3$?

Comment: ha[][][][][][][[

Comment: too many $\forall$ symbols, not enough words :(

Comment: Your constraint ($\forall |z|\geq 3$) doesn't imply the Liouville result you use; rather, you have the generic $f(z) = a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3$.  Now just equate coefficients of the power series/polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only have the estimate

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant c\lvert z\rvert^3\tag{1}$$

for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 3$, you can't assume that

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^3}$$

is an entire function. It may have a pole in $0$.

However, $(1)$ says, by the Cauchy-estimates, that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $3$. Then

$$a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 \equiv a_0 + a_1 iz - a_2 z^2 - a_3 i z^3$$

tells you that $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$, so the only functions with these properties are the constant functions.